CI 3.0 - Controller file where I want to download uploaded picture from portal customer dashboard
Customer Dashboard - Where on first customer login customer will see a pop-up form after his first login, and fill out the form and upload the pdf and picture.
And Admin can see the entries on the admin dashboard page, admin can see all fields and able to download the pdf file but not able to get the first file i.e. either jpg/png/pdf file. But able to download second file that can be the JPG / PNG / PDF etc format.
You can check the controller code -
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once 'Admin_controller.php';

class Client extends Admin_Controller {
   public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->check_login();
       $this->load->model('client_model');
   }
   public function index(){
       $data = $this->data;
       $list=array();
       $data['list']=$list;
       $data['page_title'] = "Online Account List";
       $this->page->showpage($data);
   }

   public function ajax_get_data_list(){
       $where = array();
       $item_list = $this->client_model->get_all($where, array('id'=>'desc'));
       if(empty($item_list)) $item_list = array();
       $record_list = array();
       if(count($item_list)>0){
           foreach ($item_list as $key => $row){
               $form_data = $row['form_data'];
               if(!empty($form_data)){
                   $form_data = json_decode($form_data, true);
               }else{
                   continue;
               }
               $record=array();
               $record[]=$form_data['form_title'];
               $record[]=$form_data['first_name'];
               $record[]=$form_data['surname'];
               $record[]=$form_data['country'];
               $record[]=$form_data['preferred_email'];
               $record[]=$form_data['preferred_phone'];
               $record[]=$row['add_timestamp'];
               $html='<div class="text-right">';
               $html.='<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="'.base_url('admin/client/detail').'" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="ajax-view-client-btn icon-btn btn btn-success btn-xs tooltips margin-right-5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-eye fa fa-white"></i></a>';
               $html.='<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="'.base_url('admin/client/delete').'" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="ajax-del-client-btn icon-btn btn btn-danger btn-xs tooltips margin-right-5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i></a>';
               $html.='</div>';
               $record[]=$html;
               $record_list[]=$record;
           }
       }
       $table_data=array('data'=>$record_list);
       echo json_encode($table_data);
   }
   public function detail(){
       $id = intval($_POST['id']);
       $condition['id'] = $id;
       $row = $this->client_model->get($condition);
       $form_data = $row['form_data'];
       if(!empty($form_data)){
           $form_data = json_decode($form_data, true);
       }else{
           $form_data = array();
           $this->json_output_error("Invalid account");
           return;
       }
       $row['form_data'] = $form_data;
       $online_form_data = $form_data;

       $message = '';
       $message .= '<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; max-width: 960px;" class="content">';
       $message .='<tbody>';
       $field_data_list = get_field_list();
       foreach($field_data_list as $section => $field_list) {
           if($section === 'photographic_id'){
               continue;
           }
           if($section == 'profile_information') {
               $section_title = "Profile Information";
           }elseif($section == 'account_information') {
               $section_title = "Account Information";
           }else{
               $section_title = "Additional Information";
           }
           $message.='<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 24px;">'.$section_title.'</td></tr>';
           foreach($field_list as $row){
               $field_name = $row['name'];
               $field_label = $row['label'];
               $field_value = get_data_value($online_form_data, $field_name);
               if(is_array($field_value)){
                   $field_value = implode(',', $field_value);
               }
               $message.='<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px;">'.$field_label.' :&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold">'.$field_value.'</span></td></tr>';
           }
       }

       $filename_arr = [];
       $section_title = "Photographic ID";
       $message.='<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 24px;">'.$section_title.'</td></tr>';
       foreach($field_data_list['photographic_id'] as $row){
           $field_name = $row['name'];
           $field_label = $row['label'];
           $field_value = get_data_value($online_form_data, $field_name);
           $file_url = base_url().UPLOADS_PATH.'/'.PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH.'/'.$field_value;
           $img = '<a href="'.($file_url).'" target="_blank" style="color: #007bff; text-decoration: underline" download>Download</a>';
           $message.='<tr><td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px; color: #555555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px;">'.$field_label.' :&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold">'.$img.'</span></td></tr>';
           $filename_arr[] = UPLOADS_PATH.'/'.PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH.'/'.$field_value;
       }
       $message .='</tbody>';
       $message .= '</table>';

       $html = $message;
       $data = array(
           'client_data' => $row,
           'html' => $html
       );
       $this->json_output_data($data);
   }
   public function delete(){
       $id = intval($_POST['id']);
       $condition['id'] = $id;
       $data = $this->client_model->delete($condition);
       $this->json_output_data($data);
   }



}



If you are really still using CodeIgniter v3.0: please keep in mind that this version is horribly outdated.

yes, you're right,
